# Por qué no puedo romper este while?

Tags: linux, shell, bucles

Estoy haciendo una aplicación sencilla a la que se le entrega una cadena y retorna el primer caracter, usé un bucle para que si quería preguntar varias veces no tuviera que abrir y abrir el archivo.

```
#! /bin/bash
while true
do
        echo -n "Digite el la cadena de la cual desea saber el primer digito: ";
        read numero;
        echo "El primer caracter es: '${numero:0:1}'";
        echo "Si desea intentar de nuevo presione 1, de lo contrario presione 2:";
        read salir;
        if $salir != $1; then
                echo "Adios :)";
                $DELAY;
                break
        fi
done
```

Lo raro es que me dice que en la linea 14 (la cual es *done*) no encuentra lo que nosotros digitamos para continuar o salir: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces me genera un bucle infinito. 1) No sé como salirme del bucle infinito, 2) No sé qué tiene que ver el done y 3) No sé cómo hacer que funcione correctamente . Agradezco su tiempo y ayuda de antemano.

Comment: Solo como un punto a tener en cuenta... a ```echo "Si desea intentar de nuevo presione 1, de lo contrario presione 2:``` no le falta un ```;``` y unas ```"```?

Comment: Es que uso un emulador online bastante básico y como entré en bucle infinito no lo puedo ver. Pero estoy casi seguro que están puestos (la ventana en la que escribo online es muy corta entonces no pude copiar todo). (:

Comment: Oh, permiteme testear en esa ventana online si es posible para comprobar el código

Comment: (https://bellard.org/jslinux/vm.html?cpu=riscv64&url=https://bellard.org/jslinux/buildroot-riscv64.cfg&mem=256) Esa es la página, sin embargo el código no sale, la única sería re-escribirlo :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código está mal escrito, tal vez lo copiaste y pegaste mal y te hacen falta comillas, además de que estás usando mal el operador de comparación y no estás asignándole ningún valor ni uso a la variable `DELAY`, además de que en tu código haces uso del caracter `;` el cuál no es necesario si tienes saltos de línea.

Tu código debería quedar algo por el estilo.

Sólo que la variable `DELAY` no está siento utilizada para nada.

```
#!/bin/bash

while :
do
    echo -n "Digite la cadena de la cual desea saber el primer digito: "
    read numero
    echo "El primer caracter es: '${numero:0:1}'"
    echo "Si desea intentar de nuevo presione 1, de lo contrario presione 2:"
    read salir
    if [[ $salir != 1 ]]
    then
            echo "Adios :)"
            sleep 2
            break
    fi
done
```

Comment: Lo de las comillas fue que al pasarlo a aquí no lo copié todo. Y lo del _DELAY_ lo vi en un foro y creí que era para darle un retraso, no sabía que había que asignarle un valor, creí que era como wait o algo así. La única diferencia entre este código y el mío es el $ en el 1 de la linea 9. Y lo probé sin el $ y me sale: _Unknow operand_ y vuelve al bucle infinito.

Comment: Hay más diferencias entre el código y la modificación que le hice. Está que en lugar de `true` yo pongo `:`, además de la forma de evaluar con el *built-in* `[[`, el caracter innecesario del `;`. Si quieres hacer una pausa, puedes usar `sleep`. En un momento lo agrego a mi respuesta.

Comment: Lo escribí así idéntico como este y me sigue saliendo _sh: 1: Unknow operand_  ):

Comment: Es que usas `sh` y no `bash`. Utiliza `bash programa.sh` o dale permisos de ejecución con `chmod u+x programa.sh` y luego córrelo con `./programa.sh`

Comment: `sh` y `bash` son diferentes programas. Por eso el código inicia con `#!/bin/bash`, a esa cadena se le conoce como *shebang* y sirve para que, cuando se le den permisos de ejecución, como con `chmod u+x programa.sh`, se corra en el programa que se indique después del `#!`, que en este caso es `/bin/bash`

Comment: @Marco solo por aclarar: por que utilizas doble corchete en el if `if [[ $salir != 1 ]]` ?  en principio con uno solo basta para ejecutar el evaluador test. Por un casual lo estas haciendo en mac?

Comment: @Jakala Utilizo el *built-in* `[[` por costumbre ya que permite hacer evaluaciones más complejas. Sé que con `[` o con `test` basta, pero me acostumbré a esa opción  avanzada de `bash`. Y no, no estoy en una Mac, estoy en Windows 10 usando WSL con Ubuntu.

Comment: ok. Lo comentaba porque me encontre una situacion hace un tiempo en la que en mac el test funcionaba correctamente con doble corchete pero en ubuntu no, y con un unico corchete funcionaba correctamente en ambos. Todavia sigo sin entender el por que, de ahi la pregunta.

Comment: Pues a simple vista me parece un problema de los *built-ins* en el shell de Mac pero también que existen como programas incluidos en `/bin`. Algo que podrías hacer para salir de la duda es usar `command -v <comando>` para ver qué es lo que estás corriendo, si un built-in, un alias o un programa dentro de la jerarquía. 
También no sé qué tipo de shell use Mac por defecto, me suena a que `dash` pero no lo sé.